# Microstation V8i can't access a reference?

Tags: graphics-editing

Working in **Microstation V8i**, in a file previously put together by someone else. I cannot access a particular polygon and whenever I put the cursor on top of it (without clicking) the little error symbol (circle with a line through it - the "no" symbol if you will) pops up next to my cursor.

If I try and click on it I get this warning `Element is in a reference with locate turned off`.  I can't select the line to turn it off or even see where it is located. All my references are turned on and in their respective folders, and nothing has been moved recently.

Has anyone gotten this warning before and if so, what does it mean/what actions can I take to be able to edit this line? I honestly just want to turn it off.

I cannot access any information about the polygon (location, type, size, etc) because of the warning message that pops up and my inability to click on/select the polygon.

Comment: Your question is way to broad.    You have told us nothing helpful except your using `Microstation V8i`.  Please provide specifics, for instance, what exactly is the content causing the problem ( the specific line ).

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I'm a relatively new microstation user, is there something I can tell you to help narrow down my problem? I can't access alot of information myself but was more curious to see if anyone had come across this same error message. I can't figure out what kind of line it is because I cannot select it at all. I'll see if I can figure at least that out and update you

Answer (score 1):

'Locate' is a setting that can be turned on and off for each reference. First, try turning on and off references and levels until you find where the polygon is. Within the Reference Toolbox, along the bottom are settings that can be toggled on of off. Select the reference you need, and click the "mouse" icon from the choices. This is the locate setting.

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by navigating to the Level Manager, find the reference where that specific level is nested in, right click on that reference to select/deselect "Locate"